# aliases for imported modules with importlib

Tags: python, import

Once you have imported `foo` module in which you have the `bar` class with

```
import importlib
foo = importlib.import_module('path/to/foo')
```

How do you do to simply call `bar.run()` instead of `foo.bar.run()`?

I guess you can to this `bar = foo.bar`
but I want to do it for all objects in foo, and I can't do it each by each, it will take too much time.

Comment: Can't you do `from foo import *` here?

Comment: no , that's the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would likely need to enumerate the exported objects from the `foo` module, and assign them to global variables. In the normal mechanism for importing modules, `*` will either match the names listed in the `__all__` variable or will grab all names that don't start with an underscore (`_`).

```py
names = getattr(foo, '__all__', [])
if not names:
  names = [n for n in foo.__dict__.keys() if n[:1] != '_']

for name in names:
  globals()[name] = getattr(foo, name)
```